# FFMPEG RTP MpegTS Muxrate

Tags: ffmpeg

I am needing an application that takes an input rtp MpegTS stream and re-muxes it, remaps the PIDs and then sends it out as an RTP MpegTS multicast. I understand FFMPEG in its current form cannot do this as the rtp_mpegts does not pick up the options from the command line.

I have started to look at the FFMPEG source to find a way to add it into to have these options. I am slightly confused by the way FFMPEG uses the AVFormatContext to pass around information. I have added a new priv_class to the rtp_mepgts which points to a class with options in it (identical to the mpegtsenc.c class) so that the options will actually be added to that context. However, it is now failing when trying to do a realloc somewhere.

Before going down the line too far - is this the correct approach to take? Is this how to add the options correctly to FFMPEG or is there another way completely I should be looking?

Answer (score 1):

1. Remmaping of PIDs can be done in ffmpeg.
   fmpeg -i input -c copy -f mpegts \
    -mpegts_original_network_id 0x1122 \
    -mpegts_transport_stream_id 0x3344 \
    -mpegts_service_id 0x5566 \
    -mpegts_service_type 0x1 \
    -mpegts_pmt_start_pid 0x1500 \
    -mpegts_start_pid 0x150 \
    -metadata service_provider="Some provider" \
    -metadata service_name="Some Channel" \
    -tables_version 5 \
    sample.ts
2. Remuxing can be done via ffmpeg using [muxrate] parameter
3. Changing RTP to UDP and to RTP can be done using multicat tool
   https://www.videolan.org/projects/multicat.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. As you suggested using those two tools in conjunction will work. It is unfortunate that multicat is linux/mac OS only and we are working on windows platforms. But vote for answer as it does provide a solution.